# Android : Varying the button's size as per screen sizes

Tags: android, xml, view, screen-size

I want to have all my views in android xml to scale up according to the screen size. Anyway I can do it. I cannot use match_parent or wrap_content in all.

This is a button in relative layout. I want to change its size according to the screen size

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/simple_b_1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/simple_b_4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/simple_check"
        android:text="1"
        android:width="66dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited

ok got it you can define deferent dimens file in values folder and name values folder like values(first default folder) values-sw480dp, values-sw600dp and values-sw700 
 values use for screen size upto 3.2 inch
values-sw480dp use for screen size from 3.3 inch to 5.7 inch
values-sw600dp use for screen size 7 inch
values-sw720dp use for screen size 10 inch android will adjust automatically all screen when you define it like that

below is example of dimens file you can define in vaules-sw480dp folder for sceen size 3.3 to 5.7 inch also you can define for rest screen size in different values folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>

   <dimen name="layout_marginBottom">38dp</dimen>
   <dimen name="layout_marginLeft">70dp</dimen>
   <dimen name="layout_marginRight">70dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

now you can use it in layout like below

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/mybutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/layout_marginBottom"<----- these   
                //are the dimens file reference it like that in Layout folder android 
                //will pick automatically

                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/layout_marginRight"

                android:background="@drawable/frame" />
```

Comment: I mean that if i use this same layout on nexus 5 as well as nexus 7 the button size should vary accordingly. Right now the sizes are fixed so if i use it in nexus 5 it is proper but if i use it in nexus 7 then the buttons are not properly formatted.

Comment: I am using multiple buttons.
The above code is just an example of how i am defining those buttons in a relative layout.

Comment: this will not scale the buttons, it will just vary the distance between them .... I want the buttons to resize as per the scale ... But i think I can use this dimen for setting up width and height of button and it may work ...